# LValue required in C

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-errors, logical-operators

I am getting the error of left operand expected but I don't know what to do cause I got this error first time.

I wrote this code:

```c
char answer1;
char answer2;
printf("Have you passed maths exam?(y - yes,n - no)");
scanf("%c", &answer1);
printf("Have you passed science exam?(y - yes,n - no");
scanf("%c", &answer2);
if (answer1 = 'y' || answer2 = 'y')
{
    printf("You get the prize of 15 rupees");
} else if (answer1 = 'y' && answer2 = 'y')
{
    printf("You get the prize of 45 rupees");
} else
{
    printf("Sorry! But you get no prize.");
}
return 0;
```

The error is:

```
if-else.c:25:38: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   25 |         if (answer1 = 'y' || answer2 = 'y'){
      |                                      ^
if-else.c:28:43: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   28 |         else if (answer1 = 'y' && answer2 = 'y'){
      |
```

Comment: Please use this info to more readably present your question: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and this [mre] to provide more useful way of code and this [ask] to make the question more answerable.

Comment: Please explain your undestanding of the difference between assignment operator `=` and boolean comparison operator `==`.

Comment: Do you want to know why `answer2` is not acceptable to compiler as lvalue while `answer1` seems to be acceptable in a very similar construct? Or do you have a different question? If you would actually ask a question, it would be easier to answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `&&` and `||` and operators have higher precedence than the `=` operator and all three operators associate left-to-right, so

```
answer1 = 'y' || answer2 = 'y'
```

is equivalent to

```
answer1 = (('y' || answer2) = 'y')
```

and

```
answer1 = 'y' && answer2 = 'y'
```

is equivalent to

```
answer1 = (('y' && answer2) = 'y')
```

The subexpressions `('y' || answer2)` and `('y' && answer2)` are not lvalues so they cannot be assigned to, but they are being used as the left operand of an assignment operator, hence the errors reported by the compiler.

---

The code should be using the equality operator `==` to test for equality, not the assignment operator `=`. The `==` operator has higher precedence than `&&` and `||` so

```
answer1 == 'y' || answer2 == 'y'
```

is equivalent to

```
(answer1 == 'y') || (answer2 == 'y')
```

and

```
answer1 == 'y' && answer2 == 'y'
```

is equivalent to

```
(answer1 == 'y') && (answer2 == 'y')
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters at least the second call of `scanf` should have the following format string

```
scanf( " %c", &answer2 );
       ^^
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters. Otherwise this call of `scanf` will read the new line character `'\n'` that is placed in the input buffer due to pressing the Enter key for the first call of `scanf`.

As for the error message in the if statements then you need to use the comparison operator `==` instead of the assignment `=`.

```
if (answer1 == 'y' || answer2 == 'y')
           ^^^^              ^^^^
```

Otherwise this if statement looks like

```
if (answer1 = ( 'y' || answer2 ) = 'y')
```

That is you are trying to assign a value to the expression `( 'y' || answer2 )`. because the assignment operator has a lower priority compared with logical operators.

But if to update your if statements

```
if (answer1 == 'y' || answer2 == 'y')
{
    printf("You get the prize of 15 rupees");
} else if (answer1 == 'y' && answer2 == 'y')
//...
```

then the second if statement will never get the control. You need to rewrite them exchanging the if statements like

```
if (answer1 == 'y' && answer2 == 'y')
{
    printf("You get the prize of 45 rupees");
} else if (answer1 == 'y' || answer2 == 'y')
{
    printf("You get the prize of 15 rupees");
} else
{
    printf("Sorry! But you get no prize.");
}
```